Does Der Freischütz need a Fully Charged Aimed Shot against an aggroed enemy?
I just tried multiple times and somehow ended up getting the achievement against the Thousand Winds Temple Ruin Guard while standing on a short pillar in the northwest, but never got it while standing on Starsnatch Cliff itself, but I didn't manage to pin down the requirements other than:
It's possible at the lowest game settings with Amber while not in the Alternate Aiming Mode accessed by hitting default R, and instead with a manually held, fully charged shot.
But given that I got tons of 2 damage and some 4 damage (weakpoint) regular shots, it seems that a fully charged Aimed Shot is necessary, can anyone disprove that?
And is it possible to get the achievement with the shot that starts combat instead of already being in combat? I think I had my Ruin Guard be in-combat with me, judging by the music and my dragon not floating with me, when I got the achievement shot?
